# How to save data from one view controller and show in another view controller using core data

Tags: ios, json, swift, database, core-data

I need help with solving one problem with `core data`. I have a news app with two view controllers. In the `main view controller` I'm loading news data in table view in custom cell. Here I have a `button, on which should I tap and save news to another view controller`. How it looks now: [How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qDHo.png) So when we `tap on this blue button, it should save news from the cell and display on second view controller`. I have created a `core data model` like this: [Core data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsZaw.png) Here is code in `my first view controller`:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UpdateTableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pecodeTableView: UITableView!
    
    private var articles = [News]()
//    private var viewModels = [NewsTableViewCellViewModel]()
    private var viewModel = NewsListViewModel()
    
    var newsTitle: String?
    var newsAuthor: String?
    var newsDesc: String?
    var urlString: String?
    var newsDate: String?
    
    private let searchVC = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    var selectedRow = Int()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pecodeTableView.delegate = self
        pecodeTableView.dataSource = self
        
        pecodeTableView.register(UINib(nibName: S.CustomCell.customNewsCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: S.CustomCell.customCellIdentifier)
        
//        fetchAllNews()
        viewModel.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        categoryMenu()
        loadData()
    }
    
    private func loadNewsData(api: String){
        let apiService = APIService(categoryCode: api)
        apiService.getNewsData {(result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let NewsOf):
                CoreData.sharedInstance.saveDataOf(news: NewsOf.articles)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error processing json data: \(error)")
               
            }
        }
    }
    
    func reloadData(sender: NewsListViewModel) {
        self.pecodeTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Networking
    private func loadData(){
        viewModel.retrieveDataFromCoreData()
    }
    
    //MARK: - UIView UImenu
    func categoryMenu(){
        var categoryAction: UIMenu{
            let menuAction = Category.allCases.map { (item) -> UIAction in
                let name = item.rawValue
                return UIAction(title: name.capitalized, image: UIImage(systemName: item.systemImage)) { [weak self](_) in
                    self?.loadNewsData(api: name)
                    self?.loadData()
                    self?.reloadData(sender: self!.viewModel)
                }
            }
            return UIMenu(title: "Change Category", children: menuAction)
        }
        let categoryButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "scroll"), menu: categoryAction)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = categoryButton
    }
    
    @IBAction func goToFavouritesNews(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: S.Segues.goToFav, sender: self)
    }
    
    private func createSearchBar() {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchVC
        searchVC.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
   
}



extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: S.CustomCell.customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CustomNewsCell
        let object = viewModel.object(indexPath: indexPath)!
        cell?.setCellWithValuesOf(object)
        cell?.saveNewsBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell?.saveNewsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCellButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell!
    }
    
    @objc func didTapCellButton(sender: FavouritesCell) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "SavedNews", in: context)
        let newNewsSave = SavedNews(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        newNewsSave.author = newsAuthor
        newNewsSave.desc = newsDesc
        newNewsSave.title = newsTitle
        do {
            try context.save()
            savedNews.append(newNewsSave)
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        } catch {
            print("Error saving")
        }
        
        print("Done")
        }
```

Also I want to show you `my parsing functions and model` for this: `*APIService.swift*`

```
import Foundation

class APIService{
    
    private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    
    public let resourceURL: URL
    private let API_KEY = "e2a69f7f9567451ba484c85614356c30"
    private let host = "https://newsapi.org"
    private let headlines = "/v2/top-headlines?"
    
    init(categoryCode: String){
        let resourceString = "\(host)\(headlines)country=us&category=\(categoryCode)&apiKey=\(API_KEY)"
        print(resourceString)
        
        guard let resourceURL = URL(string: resourceString) else {
            fatalError()
        }
        self.resourceURL = resourceURL
    }
    //MARK: - Get News
    func getNewsData(completion: @escaping (Result<Articles, Error>) -> Void){
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error{
                completion(.failure(error))
                print("DataTask error: - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else{
                print("Empty Response")
                return
            }
            print("Response status code: - \(response.statusCode)")
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Empty Data")
                return
            }
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Articles.self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(jsonData))
                }
            }catch let error{
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
}
```

And here is `NewsModel.swift`:

```
import Foundation

struct Articles: Codable {
    let articles: [News]
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case articles = "articles"
    }
}

struct News: Codable {
    let author: String?
    let source: Source
    let title: String
    let description: String?
    let url: URL?
    let urlToImage: URL?
    let publishedAt: String?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case author = "author"
        case title = "title"
        case url = "url"
        case urlToImage = "urlToImage"
        case publishedAt = "publishedAt"
        case description = "description"
        case source = "source"
    }
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let name: String?
}
```

Here is my code in `CustomNewsCell.swift`:

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomNewsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func btnFavPress(cell: CustomNewsCell)
}

private var loadImage = LoadToImage()
private var formatDate = FormatDate()

class CustomNewsCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomNewsDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var saveNewsBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageOutlet: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    func setCellWithValuesOf(_ news: SavedNews){
        updateUI(title: news.title, url: news.url, urlToImage: news.urlToImage, publishedAt: news.publishedAt, author: news.author ?? "No author", description: news.desc, source: news.source)
    }
    
    private func updateUI(title: String?, url: URL?, urlToImage: URL?, publishedAt: String?, author: String, description: String?, source: String?){
        
        //title
        self.titleLabel.text = title
        self.authorLabel.text = author
        self.descLabel.text = description
        
        
        //date
        let dateString = formatDate.formatDate(from: publishedAt ?? "")
        let date = formatDate.formatDateString(from: dateString)
        self.dateLabel.text = date
        
        
        //image
        guard let urlToImageString = urlToImage else {return}
        imageOutlet.image = nil
        loadImage.getImageDataFrom(url: urlToImageString) { [weak self] data in
            guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.imageOutlet.image = UIImage(named: "noImage")
                }
                return
            }
            self?.imageOutlet.image = image
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.btnFavPress(cell: self)
    }
}
```

First time I've tried with `delegate method for this blue button`, but now as you can see I've created a `selector method`. Maybe it's not correct and need to fix it. Here is the code in the `second view controller`, which should `show saved news from first view controller`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var savedNews = [SavedNews]()

class FavouriteNewsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var favTableView: UITableView!
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var result: [SavedNews] = []
    
    var newsTitleNew: String?
    var newsDescNew: String?
    var newsAuthor: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        favTableView.delegate = self
        favTableView.delegate = self
        fetch()
//        loadSavedNews()
        
        favTableView.register(UINib(nibName: S.FavouriteCell.favouriteCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: S.FavouriteCell.favouriteCellIdentifier)
        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
//        fetch()
        favTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func goToNewsFeed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: S.Segues.goToNewsFeed, sender: self)
    }
    
}

extension FavouriteNewsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return savedNews.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = favTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: S.FavouriteCell.favouriteCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FavouritesCell
        
        let newRslt: SavedNews!
        newRslt = savedNews[indexPath.row]
        cell.favAuthor.text = newRslt.author
        cell.favDesc.text = newRslt.desc
        cell.favTitle.text = newRslt.title
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<SavedNews>(entityName: "SavedNews")
        
        do {
            savedNews = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

And code for `cell for this controller`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavouritesCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var favImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favAuthor: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

If somebody can help with this, it will be amazing. Because I really don't how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be popping a view controller when the button is tapped; Do you want to go back to a previously displayed view controller with an additional favourite or do you want to display a new view controller?  If so, does it show all of the favourites or just the one for which the button was tapped?

Comment: I've tried to go back and show favourites, but nothing happened. Need to tap on the button and it should display the same in another view controller. Seems we need to save it and pass the data or something else...

Comment: If you are moving forward then you can simply pass the appropriate `News` instance. No need for Core Data. If you are using a segue then you need to pass the data in `prepare(for segue:,sender:)`. If you aren't using a segue then you simply instantiate the destination view controller, set the property and the push the new view controller.

Comment: But I need that it will be saved in the second view controller. So user add news to favourite and then he can see this saved news in second view controller.

Comment: Ok, but really those are two different things.  You can update the data in Core Data to save the fact that this item is now a favourite, but you can simply pass the item directly to the detail view controller; No need for it to rely on reading core data

Comment: Okay, but how to pass it to the custom cell? Because in perform segue I don't know how to access the cell